# Starting two times firefox on different monitors

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line, multiple-monitors, autostart

i'm using openthinclient and try to create a script that starts iceweasel in fullscreen on a machine two times on different monitors (each instance on a different monitor).

Is that even possible?

At the moment I only run

```
iceweasel -new-window http://stackoverflow.com -new-window http://www.google.com
```

So two instance are running. How can I move the windows to other monitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember well on Fedora you can choose the display before starting a windowed app by setting the var `DISPLAY`:

```
xhost +localhost
DISPLAY=:0.0
gui-app
```

The first number of `DISPLAY=:X.0` is the number of the display.

Try with your OS (Debian?)

---

The list of commands that works for me on Centos 7:

```
xhost +localhost
DISPLAY=:0
firefox     => openned on the first monitor
DISPLAY=:1
firefox     => openned on the second monitor
```

Comment: I tried the following:

xhost +localhost
DISPLAY=:2.0
gui-app
iceweasel -new-window http://www.google.com/ 

with display 0.0 to 2.0 without any changes. It's Debian OS

Comment: Try this command: `cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done` to get the right display number

Comment: This command gives me `:0 :1`. If I set `DISPLAY=:1` it goes well on the second monitor (the second digit is not mandatory). I'm working on Centos7 and I've no Debian to test now...

Comment: Your answer is probably correct but I always get :0 with your command on both screens :(

Comment: You should take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435870/linux-force-application-to-full-screen-on-a-specific-display?rq=1. You may have one logical display and it may be possible to set the position via `xterm -geometry WthxHt+X+Y`